# How do I define plugin in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I am currently rewriting my small minecraft plugin project from java to kotlin, and I would like to use the BukkitScheduler. For that I need to define plugin, which I have no clue how to do in Kotlin.

My question is, how to 'translate' my java code to kotlin?

Note: I am still a beginner in kotlin, and I learn as i move forward with my project. I have also posted this on the spigot forums, but since most of the people there work with java, I believe I'm going to receive an answer faster here.

Thanks!

```java
private Main plugin;

    public ClassName(Main plugin){
        this.plugin = plugin;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty helpful wiki post on Spigot about how to set up your workspace that you can find [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/how-to-use-kotlin-in-your-plugins/).

Besides that things should work pretty much the same as a normal plugin in Java. Here's how creating your plugin would work:

```
class Main : JavaPlugin() {
    override fun onEnable() {

    }
}
```

and then in ClassName you'd have the following:

```
class ClassName(private val plugin: Main) {

}
```

The above code is equivalent to the following code snippets:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        ClassName className = new ClassName();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ClassName {
    private Main plugin;
    public ClassName(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }
}
```

Just a heads up, if you write something in Java and want to see how to do it in Kotlin, IntelliJ will convert it for you. All you need to do is right click on the file and at the bottom there will be "Convert Java File to Kotlin File".